# Exercício de ordenação de tuplas

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou apanhando em um exercício de Python. Ele pede o seguinte:

> Crie uma função que:
>
> - Receba uma lista de tuplas (dados), um inteiro (chave, zero por padrão igual) e um booleano (reverso, falso por padrão).
> - Retorne dados ordenados pelo item indicado pela chave e em ordem decrescente se reverso for verdadeiro.

Os conhecimentos que tenho para resolvê-lo são o conhecimento de como criar funções e mais a seguinte explicação:

> O interpretador tem definidas algumas funções builtin, incluindo
>   `sorted()`, que ordena sequências, e `cmp()`, que faz comparações entre
>   dois argumentos e retorna `-1` se o primeiro elemento for maior , `0`
>   (zero) se forem iguais ou `1` se o último for maior. Essa função é usada
>   pela rotina de ordenação, um comportamento que pode ser modificado.
>
> Exemplo:

```
dados = [(4, 3), (5, 1), (7, 2), (9, 0)]

# Comparando pelo último elemento
def _cmp(x, y):
    return cmp(x[-1], y[-1])

print 'Lista:', dados

# Ordena usando _cmp()
print 'Ordenada:', sorted(dados, _cmp)
```

Saída:

```
Lista: [(4, 3), (5, 1), (7, 2), (9, 0)]
Ordenada: [(9, 0), (5, 1), (7, 2), (4, 3)]
```

#### Dúvidas:

Não entendi bem a frase "zero por padrão igual", esse "igual" aí parece estar sobrando na frase.

Gostaria de resolver aproveitando as funções `sorted()` e `cmp()` e não implementando ordenação do zero (acho que essa é a intenção do exercício também). Entendo que deveria criar uma função `_cmp()` baseada em `cmp()` e recebendo como parâmetros opcionais `chave` e `reverso`. Porém o exemplo chama a função assim `sorted(dados, _cmp)` e eu entendo que `sorted()` irá chamar internamente a função `_cmp()` passando dois parâmetros somente (os dois elementos que deverão ser comparados). Eu até tentei resolver passando os dois parâmetros opcionais para `_cmp` mas isso não faz muito sentido e empaquei aí... ficou assim:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def ordenar(dados, chave = 0, reverso = False):
    return (dados, _cmp(chave, reverso))

def _cmp(x, y, chave = 0, reverso = False):
    if reverso == False:
        return cmp(x[chave], y[chave])
    else:
        return cmp(y[chave], x[chave])

dados = [(4, 3), (5, 1), (7, 2), (9, 0)]

print dados
print ordenar(dados, 1, True)
```

Saída:

```
[(4, 3), (5, 1), (7, 2), (9, 0)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apl.py", line 16, in <module>
    print ordenar(dados, 1, True)
  File "apl.py", line 5, in ordenar
    return (dados, _cmp(chave, reverso))
  File "apl.py", line 9, in _cmp
    return cmp(x[chave], y[chave])
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Porque não fazer só: https://repl.it/repls/StarkCrowdedTriangle? Quanto ao erro é porque estás a chamar `_cmp(0, True)` neste caso, e não podes depois fazer `x[chave]` pois da maneira que construiste `x = 0`, e não podes pedir o indice de um inteiro como se fosse um iterável (obviamente (; )

Comment: @Miguel Acredito que o material que estou seguindo não forneceu o subsídio necessário para resolver o exercício. Não ensinou a criar lambdas, por exemplo, nem a usar uma função como chave (`key`) de `sorted()`. Seu código ajudou a avançar no exercício porém, mostrando que `sorted()` é a função que pode receber `reverse` e não `_cmp()`. Se não houver como resolver o exercício com o subsídio que tenho irei desconsiderá-lo (e ficar um pouco de pé atrás com o material). Por favor confirme para mim se esse código é a forma mais fácil de fazer, e se quiser colocá-lo em uma resposta irei aceitá-la.

Comment: É a forma pythonica de fazer, é como vais fazer talvez numa próxima fase, se desenvolveres em python projetos do 'mundo real' será assim. Mas não sei se é requisito do exercício fazer como apontaste, dessa mais 'de raiz', por isso não coloquei logo como resposta, podia não resolver da maneira que querias. E quanto ao erro espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando ao "*zero por padrão igual*", acho que a palavra "igual" de fato sobrou aí. Quanto à função `cmp`, ela foi removida do Python 3 e, mesmo que sua pergunta cita a versão 2.7, não vejo motivos para, atualmente, estudá-la ou até mesmo utilizar tal versão. Recomendo fortemente que passe a estudar direto a versão 3 do Python.

A forma mais fácil que eu vejo de resolver este problema é utilizar a função `sorted` em conjunto com a função `itemgetter` do módulo `operator`.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def ordenar(dados, chave = 0, reverso = False):
  return sorted(dados, key=itemgetter(chave), reverse=reverso)
```

Assim, se definido `dados` como:

```
dados = [(4, 3), (5, 1), (7, 2), (9, 0)]
```

Tem-se os resultados:

```
>>> ordenar(dados)
[(4, 3), (5, 1), (7, 2), (9, 0)]

>>> ordenar(dados, chave=1)
[(9, 0), (5, 1), (7, 2), (4, 3)]

>>> ordenar(dados, chave=1, reverso=True)
[(4, 3), (7, 2), (5, 1), (9, 0)]
```

A função `itemgetter` retorna uma função que acessa uma determinada chave de um objeto passado via parâmetro para essa segunda função. Por exemplo, fazer `f = itemgetter(5)` e depois chamar `f(x)`, será retornado o valor de `x[5]`.

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/SeparateGreatArchitecture) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/XxvJh8)</sup>